# Error injecting: public org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver

Tags: jenkins, maven-3

When the folloiwng junit jenkins test case is executed : https://github.com/ch007m/jenkins-job-dsl/blob/main/src/test/java/dev/snowdrop/MavenJobDSLTest.java, then the jenkins job raises this error related to an Eclipse Either/sisu injection problem

```
=== Starting dev.snowdrop.MavenJobDSLTest
[...truncated 1.32 KB...]
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting: public org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.setMetadataResolver(org.eclipse.aether.impl.MetadataResolver)
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.VersionResolver
    for the 1st parameter of org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.<init>(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:127)
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.LegacyRepositorySystem
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem

1 error
      role: org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem
  roleHint: 
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:131)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:110)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:137)
    at hudson.maven.MavenUtil.createEmbedder(MavenUtil.java:211)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1321)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1124)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1076)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1059)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:985)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:689)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:513)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1907)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting: public org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.setMetadataResolver(org.eclipse.aether.impl.MetadataResolver)
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.VersionResolver
    for the 1st parameter of org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.<init>(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:127)
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.LegacyRepositorySystem
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem
```

Here are the dependencies defined

```
testCompile("org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.5")
testCompile("org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:3.6.3")
testCompile('org.apache.maven:maven-compat:3.6.3')
testCompile("org.jenkins-ci.lib:lib-jenkins-maven-embedder:3.15")
testCompile("org.jvnet.hudson:hudson-maven-embedder:3.2")
testCompile 'org.jenkins-ci.main:maven-plugin:3.8@jar'
```

Do I miss a dependency or do we have a classloading issue, .... ?

Cheers

Charles

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem after unzipping the content of the jpi archive locally for the junit test - see: https://github.com/ch007m/jenkins-job-dsl/blob/4917f812106351ced36243c2bd804957d0801735/build.gradle#L78

In this case, we dont have anymore class conflicts reported by eclipse sisu/guice

Comment: How to use jar instead of jpi in the code(using jenkins test harness)? I am also stuck with the same issue
`Error injecting: void org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.setLogger(org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.LoggerFactory)
  at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)`